# Wubi Error For Uuntu

Tags: wubi

I wanted to install Ubuntu through Wubi but I get and error.
Here's my log: [Wubi Log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bsrKA3MIxl0URJbrl_F0KgPsOyCV5pdkU0G3LnmIi-k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you're using Windows 8 or better, then you can't run Wubi. Also, why would you want to install through WUBI?!?!??! Just install through a virtual machine or a CD or DVD or just use it as live.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu!

From the log file you posted it seems you are using Windows 10 Home Single Language version (build 10586 - better known as Threshold 2 update):

```
01-19 14:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 10 Home Single Language
01-19 14:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
01-19 14:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=10586
```

Unfortunately Wubi is no longer supported and not over Windows 7.
From Windows 8 mostly because of the [release of Secure Boot](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986&page=2&p=13276572#post13276572) and a completely different boot system it is no longer possible to install this way - by default, and other way are not supported as well.

**Possible solutions:**

- Use Ubuntu in a virtual machine (for example in VMWare Player - it is free for home use and also Ubuntu is well supported in this environment)
- Resize your Windows partition, create a new independent one from the free space (or install it to a separate disk) and create dual boot.

I hope I could answer your question. :)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, [please mark it as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)